# how get "The Offer Listing" using amazon web service?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I want to get the "[offer-listing](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/161729134X/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=all)" using  amazon API.
I have explored by myself but there is not clue to get it.
it would be nice if someone suggest me the API end point to get the offer-listing or alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can either scrap the offering page or use the Amazon's Product's API and call:

1. GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU to get offer listing including your self(you can use $request->setExcludeMe(TRUE) to exclude your self)
2. GetMyPriceForSKU to get just your offer listing

This API calls will return Landing price,Shipping price,Listing price where Landing price is your selling price + shipping price. None of above API call includes seller's name or any identity, so if you'r after seller's name and selling price you better of scrapping the offering page.

Here is the code I used:

```
$asin amazon product's ASIN
$sku is amazon product's SKU
$pos_data array contains all Amazon API's credentials
$fba_check is 'Y' or 'N' whether the ASIN is FBA(Fulfilled by Amazon) or not

function init_pro_api($asin, $sku, $pos_data, $fba_check)
{
    $try = 0;
    while($try < 2)
    {
        $offers_list = "";
        $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = $pos_data['azn_access_key'];
        $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = $pos_data['azn_secret_access_key'];
        $APPLICATION_NAME = $pos_data['azn_app_name'];
        $APPLICATION_VERSION = $pos_data['azn_app_version'];
        $MERCHANT_ID = $pos_data['azn_merchant_id'];
        $MARKETPLACE_ID = $pos_data['azn_marketplace_id'];
        $platform = $pos_data['azn_platform_variant'];


        if($platform == "uk")
        {
            $serviceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/Products/2011-10-01";
        }
        else
            $serviceURL = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";

        $DATE_FORMAT = "Y-m-d";

        $config = array(
            'ServiceURL' => $serviceURL,
            'ProxyHost' => null,
            'ProxyPort' => -1,
            'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
        );

        $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client($AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, $APPLICATION_NAME, $APPLICATION_VERSION, $config);

        // Get My Price
        $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyPriceForSKURequest();
        $request->setSellerId($MERCHANT_ID);
        $request->setMarketplaceId($MARKETPLACE_ID);

        $sku_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_SellerSKUListType();
        $sku_list->setSellerSKU($sku);
        $request->setSellerSKUList($sku_list);

        $my_offer = invokeGetMyPriceForSKU($service, $request, $fba_check);

        // Get Other Sellers Lowest Offering Price
        $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetLowestOfferListingsForSKURequest();
        $request->setSellerId($MERCHANT_ID);
        $request->setMarketplaceId($MARKETPLACE_ID);
        $request->setItemCondition("New");
        $request->setExcludeMe(TRUE);

        $sku_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_SellerSKUListType();
        $sku_list->setSellerSKU($sku);
        $request->setSellerSKUList($sku_list);

        $other_low_offers = invokeGetLowestOfferListingsForSKU($service, $request);

        if($my_offer != "" or $my_offer != NULL)
        {
            $offers_list["MyOffer"] = $my_offer;
        }

        if($other_low_offers != "" or $other_low_offers != NULL)
        {
            $offers_list["OtherOffer"] = $other_low_offers;
        }

        if(isset($offers_list["OtherOffer"][0]))
            if($offers_list["OtherOffer"][0] != "")
                break;
        $try++;
    }
    return $offers_list;
}
function invokeGetMyPriceForSKU(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request, $fba_check)
{
    try
    {
        $my_response_data = "";
        $pre_check_xml_data = array();
        $xml_feed_counter = 0;
        $response = $service->GetMyPriceForSKU($request);

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $xml_data = $dom->saveXML();

        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
        $doc->loadXML($xml_data);
        $offer_length = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Offer')->length;
        $fba_index = "";
        $normal_index = "";

        for($o = 0; $o < $offer_length; $o++)
        {
            $pre_check_xml_data[$o]["LandedPrice"] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('LandedPrice')->item($o)->lastChild->nodeValue;
            $pre_check_xml_data[$o]["ListingPrice"] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ListingPrice')->item($o)->lastChild->nodeValue;
            $pre_check_xml_data[$o]["Shipping"] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Shipping')->item($o)->lastChild->nodeValue;
            $pre_check_xml_data[$o]["FulfillmentChannel"] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('FulfillmentChannel')->item($o)->nodeValue;
            if($fba_check == "Y")
            {
                if($doc->getElementsByTagName('FulfillmentChannel')->item($o)->nodeValue == "AMAZON")
                {
                    $fba_index = $o;
                    break;
                }
            }
            elseif($fba_check == "N")
            {
                if($doc->getElementsByTagName('FulfillmentChannel')->item($o)->nodeValue == "MERCHANT")
                {
                    $normal_index = $o;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if($fba_check == "Y")
        {
            if($fba_index === "")
            {
                $my_response_data[0]["LandedPrice"] = "";
                $my_response_data[0]["ListingPrice"] = "";
                $my_response_data[0]["Shipping"] = "";
                $my_response_data[0]["Fulfillment"] = "";
                return $my_response_data;
            }
            else
            {
                $my_response_data[0] = $pre_check_xml_data[$fba_index];
                return $my_response_data;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $my_response_data[0] = $pre_check_xml_data[$normal_index];
            return $my_response_data;
        }
    }
    catch(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex)
    {
        echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
        echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
        echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
        echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
    }
}
function invokeGetLowestOfferListingsForSKU(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
{
    try
    {
        $response_data = "";
        $counter = 0;
        $response = $service->getLowestOfferListingsForSKU($request);

        $getLowestOfferListingsForSKUResultList = $response->getGetLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult();
        foreach($getLowestOfferListingsForSKUResultList as $getLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult)
        {
            if($getLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult->isSetProduct())
            {
                $product = $getLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult->getProduct();

                if($product->isSetLowestOfferListings())
                {
                    $lowestOfferListings = $product->getLowestOfferListings();
                    $lowestOfferListingList = $lowestOfferListings->getLowestOfferListing();
                    foreach($lowestOfferListingList as $lowestOfferListing)
                    {
                        if($lowestOfferListing->isSetQualifiers())
                        {
                            $qualifiers = $lowestOfferListing->getQualifiers();

                            if($qualifiers->isSetFulfillmentChannel())
                            {
                                $response_data[$counter]["Fulfilled_By"] = $qualifiers->getFulfillmentChannel();
                            }
                            if($qualifiers->isSetShippingTime())
                            {
                                $shippingTime = $qualifiers->getShippingTime();
                                if($shippingTime->isSetMax())
                                {
                                    $response_data[$counter]["ShippingTime"] = $shippingTime->getMax();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if($lowestOfferListing->isSetPrice())
                        {
                            $price1 = $lowestOfferListing->getPrice();
                            if($price1->isSetLandedPrice())
                            {
                                $landedPrice1 = $price1->getLandedPrice();
                                if($landedPrice1->isSetAmount())
                                {
                                    $response_data[$counter]["LandedPrice"] = $landedPrice1->getAmount();
                                }
                            }
                            if($price1->isSetListingPrice())
                            {
                                $listingPrice1 = $price1->getListingPrice();
                                if($listingPrice1->isSetAmount())
                                {
                                    $response_data[$counter]["ListingPrice"] = $listingPrice1->getAmount();
                                }
                            }
                            if($price1->isSetShipping())
                            {
                                $shipping1 = $price1->getShipping();
                                if($shipping1->isSetAmount())
                                {
                                    $response_data[$counter]["Shipping"] = $shipping1->getAmount() . "\n";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($getLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult->isSetError())
            {
                $error = $getLowestOfferListingsForSKUResult->getError();
                if($error->isSetMessage())
                {
                    $response_data = $error->getMessage() . "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        return $response_data;
    }
    catch(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex)
    {
        echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
        echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
        echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
        echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Amazon MWS products API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/186-5996206-2727469?ie=UTF8&group=products&section=products&version=latestl) like Keyur states.  They provide PHP, C#, and Java example code and it's easy to work with.

If you want real-time price change notifications on products you are currently selling, subscribe to the `AnyOfferChangedNotification` notification.  They have example code for that too.  http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing some stuff with this right now and, if it helps anyone, I'm using the Advertising API and have found that if you make a request like this:

```
String requestString = "Service=AWSECommerceService"
    + "&Version=2009-03-31"
    + "&Operation=ItemLookup"
    + "&AssociateTag=some-associate-tag"
    + "&ItemId=" + your-item-id
    + "&ResponseGroup=BrowseNodes,OfferFull,ItemAttributes";
```

then you can look at the XPath //detailpageurl and you should get what you were expecting.